# CSS Text in ListItems not wrapping

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/qv8mg/

I'm trying to get text within an li to wrap on the browser window, in this case an iphone width:320px.

I can get it to wrap using `word-wrap:break-word;`css, but it breaks in the middle of works and mades it hard to read.

What can I get it to do to autowrap like it's supposed to, break at the spaces?

Comment: It looks like in your fiddle you have non-breaking space characters in between the words … so if you don’t want the behavior that those trigger, then don’t put them in there in the first place …

Comment: did u try word-break:break-all??

Comment: @CBroe where are you seeing non-breaking space characters?

Comment: you're right, wow...I missed that - thanks for pointing that out